# There Is Something Wrong Either With My Code or With My Understanding of It

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

The challenge here is to create a function that once the users enters their age, it would tell them how much time they have left if they lived to be 90 years old - in days, weeks, and months, provided there are 365 days each year, 52 weeks, and 12 months.

This is the code I wrote for the challenge, following all rules we've covered with the teacher so far...
But when I run it, it says NaN, and I have no idea why...

```js
function lifeInWeeks(age) {

    var maxDays = 90*365;
    var maxWeeks = 90*52;
    var maxMonths = 90*12;  
    
    console.log("You have approximately " + maxDays-(age*365) + " days, " + maxWeeks-(age*52) + " weeks, and " + maxMonths-(age*12) + " left.");
      

}

lifeInWeeks(27)
```

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem. _"There is something wrong..."_ is definitely not a helpful "summary"

Comment: put your equations in parthenthese to ensure that the `+` between the string and numbers are concatenating the entire result of your equations (so just the lhs)

Comment: If you're using somewhat modern javascript, you can simplify the concatenation with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: @NickParsons thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "-" and "+". JS is expecting the whole thing to be a mathematical equation and then fails, because your Strings are obvisously not numbers.

To make JS handle the "+" as String concatenation, you need to wrap your actual mathematical expressions with brackets:

```
  console.log("You have approximately " + (maxDays - (age * 365)) + " days, " + (maxWeeks - (age * 52)) + " weeks, and " + (maxMonths - (age * 12)) + " left.");
```

Comment: The `+` is not the problem. Nor is the `-`. It's the [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of the operators and in which order the JS engine interprets them. If you replace every `-` with a `+` without adding any `( )` it will work (= not produce a `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using two types of data in console.log(), `strings` and `methods`.

You can wrap your function calls in (), but you can also use commas instead of +, when you have different kinds of data to log.

```js
function lifeInWeeks(age) {

    var maxDays = 90*365;
    var maxWeeks = 90*52;
    var maxMonths = 90*12;  
    
    console.log("You have approximately", maxDays-(age*365) , " days,", maxWeeks-(age*52), "weeks, and", maxMonths-(age*12), "left.");
      

}

lifeInWeeks(27)
```